# How to display the below symbol in Jqmath

Tags: jqmath

[image]

I tried something like this ${TXU}↖{⏜}$ but the arc is coming size of one letter

Answer (score 2):

Finally i am able to resolve by using \html in jqMath and CSS to stretch.

```
${TXU}↖{ \html "&lt;span class='stretch'&gt;⏜&lt;/span&gt;"}$
```

and the CSS is

```
.stretch{
    transform: scale(3,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(3,1);
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

Hope this helps some one.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, jqMath doesn't do horizontal stretching yet. For advanced formatting like this I suggest you try MathJax, at least for now. (I am the jqMath author.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, is MathJax also supports same syntax as jqMath? because all my thousands of formulas are in jqMath :-(

Comment: No, I don't think MathJax support jqMath syntax yet.